# What is a pivot route?

Tags: ember.js

What is a pviot route? I see this term from time to time, but haven't been able to find a definition of what it is. I'm not even sure if it remains relevant post-router-facelift. Can anyone fill me in on what **pivot route** means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you transition from `foo/bar/baz` to `foo/bar/boo`, the pivot route is `bar`, going from `foo/bar/baz` to `/foo/user` the pivot route is `foo`. So the pivot route is the parent route of both the start and the target route where you are transitioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the unique technique of using an instance to be able to "move" around inside a network. It is just a terminology which is used.

You may find [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-nested-loading-routes/2895) helpful:

> The loading state resolution that occurs when transitioning between
>   two routes is not fundamentally different from the full page reload
>   example; there's only one extra constraint, which is that by default,
>   Ember will stop looking for nested loading routes about the **shared
>   parent route (aka the "pivot" route)**. In this case, FooRoute is the
>   pivot route.

Comment: hmmm, sorry although in the abstract your answer is meaningful, in the specific context of Ember.js it doesn't mean much to me. Can you give a concrete example of what a pivot route would look like in Ember, and how one would use it?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston:- It is just a terminology which is used. I dont think you will find any particular document which will explain you that in context of ember.js. You may check out this: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Comment: @MichaelJohnston:- Updated my answer. Found a link where you may get something useful. Hope that helps :)